Flattening so that only pairs remain
Surely this will have been asked before ... but I cannot find an answer.
I have lists of pairs wherein the pairs might be embedded to any level and not necessarily all at the same level. For example,
l={{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {{{{5, 6}, {7,8}}, {{9, 10}, {11,12}}}}
I want to flatten the list to the point where only the pairs remain. I use:
Partition[ Flatten[l], 2]
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}
which removes all the deep structure before recreating it.
Is there a better way. I've experimented with Cases and the options of Flatten but not achieved an equivalent result.

Cases[l, {__Integer}, -1] or Activate[Flatten[l /. {i__Integer} :> Inactive[{i}]]]

You can use Level:
Level[l, {-2}]


This is nice. I wasn't aware of Level[] but this is exactly what I was seeking.

l = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {{{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{9, 10}, {11, 12}}}}};


Using Replace:
Replace[l, v_ /; TensorRank[v] > 1 :> Splice@Flatten[v, TensorRank[v] - 2], 1]


{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}

Or using Cases:
Cases[l, _?VectorQ, \[Infinity]]


{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12}}

